# diagram-style tree control

Tags: c#, diagram

I would like to create ui looking like the figure below. I think I can easily create that kind of image on picturebox. But each node should be selectable and right- or left-clickable. I guess that I can create a button for each node but I am afraid that I might have to create new UI control. Is there anything already done for this?

Update: Hmm...there are actually too many. I was more interested in open source projects and found following.

- http://www.dalssoft.com/diagram/screenshots.aspx
- http://code.google.com/p/nshape/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything already done for this?

There should be a lot of options but from self experience we use [yFiles Web](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_web_about.html) for an internal Project and are pretty satisfied with the results.

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of looking for open source or advice for DIY. But yFiles looks great.